# Fetch the external json file through Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs

I have try to fetch the json data by using Angular JS. I have successfully fetch through static json data. But now I have try to fetch through external JSON file. Below is my code & there output :

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyInfo">
<head>

    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="MyInfoFunction">
    <ul> 
    <li ng-repeat="item in myinfoVariable">
            <div>
            <h3> {{item.name }}</h3>
            <p> {{item.city}}</p>
            <p> {{item.state}}</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    </li>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**data.json** - js/data.json

```
[
        {
            "name"       : "myname1",
            "city": "mycity1",
            "state" :  "mystate2"
        },
        {
            "name"       : "myname2",
            "city": "mycity2",
            "state" :  "mystate2"
        },
        {
            "name"       : "myname3",
            "city": "mycity3",
            "state" :  "mystate3"
        }
]
```

**controllers.js** : js/controllers.js

```
 var nameSpace = angular.module("MyInfo", []);

nameSpace.controller("MyInfoFunction", function MyInfoFunction($scope, testService)  {

    function Init() {
      $scope.data = {};
      testService.getData().then(function(data) {
          console.log(data)        
      });
   }
   Init();
});


nameSpace.service('testService', function ($http) {
    this.getData = function () {
        return $http.get('js/data.json');
    }
});
```

**Output :**

> - {{item.name }}
>
>   {{item.city}}
>
>   {{item.state}}

I have try to fetch but unable to get the data. What am I doing wrong please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your controller is messy and incorrect, extra `}` & `)`

```
nameSpace.controller("MyInfoFunction", function MyInfoFunction($scope, testService)  {

    function Init() {
      $scope.data = {};
      testService.getData().then(function(data) {
          $scope.myinfoVariable = data.data;
         // console.log(data)        
      });
   }
   Init();
});
```

your .json should be like

```
[
 {"name":"a","city":"b","state":"c"},
 {"name":"x","city":"y","state":"z"}
]
```

if your data.json file is in inside of the `js` folder then the getting json should be like

```
 this.getData = function () {
    return $http.get('js/data.json');
}
```

Comment: that means your angular part is working check whether data is  coming ?

Comment: no data is not coming @KalhanoToressPamuditha. Same blank screen showing only.

Comment: Please help to find out I am unable to fetch my json data.

Comment: page loads only, unable to see that demo.

Comment: oh there is a problem with plunker. it will work after sometime. i update the answer please check.

Comment: I have already found this & update in my code. Now blank screen is showing.

Comment: `$scope.myinfoVariable = data.data;` line added please check the answer again

Comment: Again white screen. No output.

Comment: One thing I want to inform you that. I have a folder named AJExample which is situated in my system desktop not in host. Inside them my index.html  & my js folder. Inside Js folder my json file & controllers.js file are there.

Comment: I got the output. Thanks. Actually my issue is that I have put the folder in desktop & I just put the folder to my htdocs & Run, I got output.

Comment: omg yeah. you need to put in the server, if not the $HTTP get is not working , $HTTP will handle by the sever :)

Comment: I got output in the form of list. How can I see in the format of table where Name, City & State are the column name. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to get `js/data.json` instead of `data.json`.

```
nameSpace.service('testService', function ($http) {
  this.getData = function () {
      return $http.get('js/data.json');
  }
});
```

You need to provide the url relative to your `index.html`.

If you are hosting your application on `http://myapp.com`, and the json file you need to get is  hosted on `http://myapp.com/js/data.json` then you can either do `$http.get("js/data.json")` either `$http.get("http://myapp.com/js/data.json")`.
However, if your json file is hosted on another website, let's say `http://mysecondapp.com`, then you need to do `$http.get("http://mysecondapp.com/data.json")`

Comment: thanks @GeoffreyB. What do mean by "need to provide the url relative to index.html."

Comment: You need to provide the url from where it can be accessed if you were to open it on your browser.

Comment: you mean that I have to put whole path or copy the whole path from browser.

Comment: Thanks but my data is not in host. Data is in my local machine (i.e. Desktop)

Comment: I have a folder named AJExample. Inside them my index.html is situated & my js folder. Inside Js folder my json file & controllers.js file are there.

Comment: I got the output. Thanks. Actually my issue is that I have put the folder in desktop & I just put the folder to my htdocs & Run, I got output.